# How to parse this particular console output and make csv?

Tags: python

I need to process console output which looks like this and make a csv from it:

```
ID,FLAG,ADDRESS,MAC-ADDRESS,HOST-NAME,SERVER,STATUS,LAST-SEEN
0   10.0.0.11     00:1D:72:29:F2:4F                lan      waiting  never
;;; test comment
1   10.0.0.19     00:13:21:15:D4:00                lan      waiting  never
2   10.0.0.10     00:60:6E:05:0C:E0                lan      waiting  never
3 D 10.0.1.199    24:E9:B3:20:FA:C7  home          server1  bound    4h54m52s
4 D 100.64.1.197  E6:17:AE:21:EA:00  Suzana-s-A51  dhcp1    bound    2h16m45s
```

I have managed to split lines but regex is not working for tabs and spaces. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The code I am using is this:

```
import csv
import re

# Open the input file in read-only mode
with open('output.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    # Open the output file in write-only mode
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        # Create a CSV writer that will write to the output file
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)

        # Read the first line of the input file (the header)
        # and write it to the output file as a single value
        # (i.e. do not split it on commas)
        header = input_file.readline()
        writer.writerow([header.strip()])

        # Iterate over the remaining lines of the input file
        for line in input_file:
            # Ignore lines that start with ";;;" (these are comments)
            if line.startswith(';;;'):
                continue

            # Split the line on newlines
            values = line.split('\n')

            line = re.sub(r'[\t ]+', ',', line)

            # Iterate over the resulting values
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                # If the value contains a comma, split it on commas
                # and assign the resulting values to the `values` list
                if ',' in value:
                    values[i:i+1] = value.split(',')

            # Write the values to the output file
            writer.writerow(values)
```

Comment: Try to use the native python CSV library https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: i am using native csv library.

Comment: What do you mean by "regex is not working for tabs and spaces"?

Comment: That is going to be a challenge since the output isn't well formatted, and doesn't have a pattern that can be used to split it in fields for a CSV.

Comment: @mkrieger1 line = re.sub(r'[\t ]+', ',', line) | this is regex which should replace all tabs and spaces with ',' but it's not correct

Comment: I think it does replace all tabs and spaces with `,`. Can you show an example where it doesn't do that?

Comment: If the columns in the output are separated by a `tab`, you can convert them directly into a `CSV`. But if you want to replace the `tab` with a `,`, you don't need regex for that. Just use the `str.replace()` method. Something like `line.replace('\t', ',')`.

Comment: Complementing @accdias answer, if your input is separated by tabs your regex should work, but if it is separated just by spaces you will have a problem because HOST NAME does not always appear on your input

Comment: Not related, but your code will be more readable if you replace that nested `with`. Something like `with open('input.txt', 'r') as input_file, open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:` is better.

Comment: Another thing that doesn't make sense is `values = line.split('\n')`. Why are you splitting on newlines? Are the records spread in multiline?

Comment: Finally, what is generating that output? Isn't easier to fix it there to generate a well formed `CSV` instead?

Comment: And one last bit: file objects that will be used by the `csv` module, [need to be opened with `newline=''`, per documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3).

Comment: @AndersonFachini If there is no value, it should place ',' instead...

Comment: @accdias i assume it is not tabs but spaces. as for splitting, in fact it is multi line output from mikrotik router dhcp entries.

Comment: If you have access to your Mikrotik, `ip dhcp-server lease print terse file=output.txt` will give you an easier output to work with.

Comment: @accdias yes, i have. but actually i think it will make it worse... can you give an example how can i use that output?

Comment: @accdias this is modified code that i wrote right now and it is better https://pastebin.com/4Wn8AZSq

Comment: I don't have access to a Mikrotik router here. If you can post the output somewhere, I can try to come up with something.

Comment: Update the question with your new code. It will make it easier for others to help as well. One thing I see in it is `if line.__contains__(' D '):` which I would replace with `if ' D ' in line:`, to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression can be handy here, make a mask, and then take each value from line read.
you can refer the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/Yw8PFi/1) and will give you great visuals.

so for each line will put a regex `reg_format=r"(\d*?)(?:\s+)(.*?)(?:\s)(?:\s*?)(\w*\.\w*\.\w*\.\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)"`

pls note that when we write to csv using `writer.writerow` it expects a list.
following would work for you, and you can tweak it as needed.

tweaked your code, and added the comments 
**Update:**
Added masking for records

```
import csv
import re

#reg_format=r"(\d*?)(?:\s+)(.*?)(?:\s)(?:\s*?)(\w*\.\w*\.\w*\.\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)"
all_fields=r"(\d*?)(?:\s+)(.*?)(?:\s)(?:\s*?)(\w*\.\w*\.\w*\.\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*)(?:\s{1,2})([\w-]{1,14})(?:\s*?)(\w+)(?:\s*)(\w+)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)"
all_fields_minus_host=r"(\d*?)(?:\s+)(.*?)(?:\s)(?:\s*?)(\w*\.\w*\.\w*\.\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*?:\w*)(?:\s{1,})([\w-]{1,14})(?:\s*?)(\w+)(?:\s*)(\w+)(?:\s*)(\w*)(?:\s*)(\w*)"
# Open the input file in read-only mode
with open('testreg.txt', 'r') as input_file:
    # Open the output file in write-only mode
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        # Create a CSV writer that will write to the output file
        writer = csv.writer(output_file)

        # Read the first line of the input file (the header)
        # and write it to the output file as a single value
        # (i.e. do not split it on commas)
        header = input_file.readline()
        writer.writerow(header.split(',')) # split by "," as write row need list
        #writer.writerow([header.strip()])

        # Iterate over the remaining lines of the input file
        for line in input_file:
            # Ignore lines that start with ";;;" (these are comments)
            if line.startswith(';;;'):
                continue
            #print(line)
            gps=re.findall(all_fields,line)
            if gps:
                line_write=(['"'+gp+'"' for gp in list(gps[0])]) # if dont need quotes, put like gp for gp in list(gps[0])]
                writer.writerow(line_write[:-1])
            else:
                gps=re.findall(all_fields_minus_host,line)
                line_write=(['"'+gp+'"' for gp in list(gps[0])]) # if dont need quotes, put like gp for gp in list(gps[0])]
                line_write.insert(4,'""')
                writer.writerow(line_write[:-2])
                
                
            #writer.writerow(line_write)
            # commented below line
            '''
            # Split the line on newlines
            values = line.split('\n')

            line = re.sub(r'[\t ]+', ',', line)

            # Iterate over the resulting values
            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                # If the value contains a comma, split it on commas
                # and assign the resulting values to the `values` list
                if ',' in value:
                    values[i:i+1] = value.split(',')

            # Write the values to the output file
            #writer.writerow(values)
            '''
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) now it is going in the right direction. It kinda works, but it does not put comma if there is no value for host-name. The output i get is this https://pastebin.com/PvpWzNDT

Comment: and it also replaces host-name from xxxxxx-s-Note20-Ultra to xxxxxx

Comment: It does not handle all edge cases, will try to make it better! , mainly need to handle  1. that group can be blank or spaces, 2. \w does not include `-` so hypen need to be valid char.

Comment: i updated output from console in my question, just fyi. i made a mistake while copying, sorry.

Comment: there was no way I could maintain the record with value(host-name) vs no value(no host name) which makes sense as regex is more like pattern matching vs data extraction :) , so had to handle them separately! for sure, there is scope of improvement here!

Comment: you did it. thank you very much! :) can you look up why i get quotes in header(last seen) and second line? this is the output https://pastebin.com/mK8QPauA

Comment: csv writter is smart, when it found `\n` at the header row, it enclosed it in quotes "" , you can change that behavior by `header = input_file.readline().rstrip()` i.e removing the \n from header.

Comment: it seems we both have learned something. :) i have more if you want(on the same topic)